# Getting a conversion error when trying to use std::find

Tags: c++, std

```
no suitable conversion function from "std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::conditional_t<true, std::_Simple_types<int, size_t, ptrdiff_t, int *, const int *, int &, const int &>>>>" to "int *" exists
```

This is shown when I hover over "std::find" in my code. I have found 0 results anywhere for what it means. I've tried removing and adding pointers, to no avail.

I'm trying to write an algorithm that creates a vector of positions where blood splatter has occurred for my game. My code looks like this:

Blood.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class Blood {
public:
    int x, y;
    std::vector<int> bloodx;
    std::vector<int> bloody;

    Blood(int x, int y);
    void makeBloodied(int x, int y);
    bool isBloodied(int x, int y);
};
```

(I've also been confused on how to insert to a vector properly, if that could be answered as a subquestion, I would appreciate it.)

Blood.cpp

```
#include "main.hpp"

Blood::Blood(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {
}

void Blood::makeBloodied(int x, int y) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    bloodx.insert(it, x);
    bloody.insert(it, y);
}

bool Blood::isBloodied(int x, int y) {
    int *resultx = std::find(bloodx.begin(), bloodx.end(), x);

}
```

Comment: `it` is uninitialized.

Comment: @codekaizer Thanks. Now do you know anything about the std::find issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to insert to a vector properly:

You can use `std::vector::push_back()` to put something at the end, or `std::vector::insert()` to insert in specific position (at given iterator).

In your case, I think you want to do:

```
bloodx.push_back(x);
```

Alternatively, if you want to insert it at an index `idx`, you can do this:

```
bloodx.insert(bloodx.begin() + idx, x);
```

> Why am I getting this error?

The use of `std::find` is correct. However, it returns `std::vector<int>::iterator`, which cannot be casted to `int *`.

I would suggest either using `auto resultx`, or alternatively casting to `int *` as follows:

```
// dereference iterator and take address (only if item found)
auto it = std::find(bloodx.begin(), bloodx.end(), x);
int *resultx = (it == bloodx.end()) ? NULL : &*resultx_it;
```

However, be careful, because if you add elements to `std::vector`, the iterators and pointers to its elements get invalidated.

> How to check if an element was found

if the element is not found, `std::find` returns the iterator `std::vector::end`, which is after the end of the vector.

```
bool found = std::find(bloodx.begin(), bloodx.end(), x) == bloodx.end();
```

Be careful here not to cast on `int *`, though, because dereferencing `std::vector::end` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Now how would I go about checking the result to see if it found a match?

Comment: `std::find` returns the `end()` iterator id the item cannot be found. Documents for `std::find`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: @JacobMcNamara I added it in the answer, but you'd learn more by reading the documentation imho.

Comment: @GillBates `Exception thrown at 0x00007FF617C9A1DE in AotDK.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000018.` I'm reading the documentation, and I'm only more confused.

Comment: @GillBates, One should never use `&*std::find(...);`.  Always use `auto it = std::find(...); if ( it != bloodx.end() ) { ... }`

Comment: @RSahu You are right, I just realized that I did what I said you shouldn't do one section later. *facepalm*

Comment: @GillBates Do you know anything about that exception?

Comment: @JacobMcNamara `0x0000000000000018` almost certainly means you have a null pointer somewhere. If you run your code in the debugging software that should have come with your development environment it will stop dead when the program crashes and allow you ti inspect the back trace to see how you got there and what variables were in play. Look for a variable that is a pointer to 0. If that doesn't have you groaning in self-loathing and then fixing the bug, ask a new question with the information you gather from the debugger.

Comment: And yes, the cppreference documentation pages can be hard to read. They prize correctness over ease of reading for the uninitiated. Sometimes [the cplusplus.com pages](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) are a better place to start as they favour readability over correctness. This  of course means the content is simplified and may be wrong. Sadly you can't get everything.

Comment: @user4581301 I got it working, but I think I'm gonna move my project over to C# so I don't have to deal with this nonsense again.

Comment: @JacobMcNamara Nooo. Please don't abandon C++ so quickly.

Comment: @GillBates I was still having some issues with it, but it turns out I wasn't indexing the position of the blood to a single vector so it was returning true in cases where it shouldn't have. Like if (5,13) had blood and (6,12) had blood, then (5,12) and (6,13) would both return true. But when I started indexing the position using mapWidth, i.e. (x+y*mapWidth), it began working exactly like I wanted it to. I'm not abandoning C++ quite yet. In fact I actually prefer it to C# as is, but I was just tired and confused lol.